# vnstat not updating

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I installed vnstat on my Ubuntu 14.04 server to track my internet usage (I have a limited monthly transfer). The database never updates, however. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling, but that doesn't work. What do I need to do to get vnstat to update and be accurate?

Answer (score 2):

```
vnstat  -u  -i eth0
```

After installation you should run command above it will trigger database for this interface,

```
vnstat -d
```

For network statistic data breakdown by day, also with: `vnstat -h` for hours.

vnstat should be runed in background by using crontab,for this you have to enable it, since after installation a cron job is created at /etc/cron.d folder:

```
vi /etc/cron.d/vnstat

*/5 * * * * vnstat /usr/sbin/vnstat.cron
```

After this you can regulary add cron entry:

```
* * * * * vnstat >> /tmp/vnstat_usage
```

Comment: Yeah I wrote my program, because cron was not working well with vnstat at the time. It may have been fixed, but the program was my workaround.

Comment: updated, can you check like this it works for me

Answer (score 2):

You need a certain amount of data to make sure the database is accurate. So you can either manually take snapshots, or do real-time analysis. I have written a program which does a constant snapshot (every 15 seconds). It is rough, but it should help. [Vnstatschedule](https://github.com/no-time/vnstatschedule)